# Difflib displays wrong output

Tags: python, difflib

I'm trying to compare two files containing key-value pairs. Here is an example of such pairs:

ORIGINAL:

`z = [1.304924111430007e-06, 1.3049474394241187e-06, 1.304856846498851e-06, 1.304754136591639e-06, 1.3047515476558986e-06, 1.3047540563617633e-06, 1.2584599050733914e-06, 1.0044863475043152e-06, 1.0044888558008254e-06, 1.0044913640973358e-06, 1.0045062486228207e-06, 1.0045211585401347e-06, 1.0045236668616387e-06, 1.0045261751942757e-06, 1.0045286838384797e-06, 1.004531191133402e-06, 1.0045336999215094e-06, 1.0045362224355439e-06, 1.004538746759441e-06, 1.0045412539447373e-06, 1.0045437622215247e-06, 1.0045462691234405e-06, 1.0045487673867214e-06, 1.0045512756837494e-06, 1.0045330661500387e-06, 1.0045314983896072e-06, 1.0045340066861176e-06, 1.0508595121822218e-06, 1.3048122384371079e-06, 1.3048147469973539e-06, 1.3048172706092426e-06, 1.3048251638664106e-06, 1.3049327764458588e-06, 1.3050280023408756e-06, 1.30500941487857e-06]\n`

FILE 2:

`z = [1.304924111430007e-06, 1.3049474394241187e-06, 1.3048568464988513e-06, 1.3047541365916392e-06, 1.3047515476558986e-06, 1.3047540563617633e-06, 1.2584599050733912e-06, 1.0044863475043152e-06, 1.0044888558008254e-06, 1.0044913640973358e-06, 1.0045062486228207e-06, 1.0045211585401347e-06, 1.0045236668616387e-06, 1.0045261751942757e-06, 1.0045286838384799e-06, 1.004531191133402e-06, 1.0045336999215094e-06, 1.0045362224355439e-06, 1.004538746759441e-06, 1.004541253944737e-06, 1.0045437622215247e-06, 1.0045462691234405e-06, 1.0045487673867214e-06, 1.0045512756837494e-06, 1.0045330661500387e-06, 1.0045314983896072e-06, 1.0045340066861176e-06, 1.0508595121822218e-06, 1.3048122384371079e-06, 1.3048147469973539e-06, 1.3048172706092426e-06, 1.3048251638664108e-06, 1.304932776445859e-06, 1.3050280023408756e-06, 1.30500941487857e-06]\n`

When I run both files trough `difflib.Differ().compare()` I get the following output which is wrong:

`'-     z = [1.304924111430007e-06, 1.3049474394241187e-06, 1.304856846498851e-06, 1.304754136591639e-06, 1.3047515476558986e-06, 1.3047540563617633e-06, 1.2584599050733914e-06, 1.0044863475043152e-06, 1.0044888558008254e-06, 1.0044913640973358e-06, 1.0045062486228207e-06, 1.0045211585401347e-06, 1.0045236668616387e-06, 1.0045261751942757e-06, 1.0045286838384797e-06, 1.004531191133402e-06, 1.0045336999215094e-06, 1.0045362224355439e-06, 1.004538746759441e-06, 1.0045412539447373e-06, 1.0045437622215247e-06, 1.0045462691234405e-06, 1.0045487673867214e-06, 1.0045512756837494e-06, 1.0045330661500387e-06, 1.0045314983896072e-06, 1.0045340066861176e-06, 1.0508595121822218e-06, 1.3048122384371079e-06, 1.3048147469973539e-06, 1.3048172706092426e-06, 1.3048251638664106e-06, 1.3049327764458588e-06, 1.3050280023408756e-06, 1.30500941487857e-06]\n', '+     z = [1.304924111430007e-06, 1.3049474394241187e-06, 1.3048568464988513e-06, 1.3047541365916392e-06, 1.3047515476558986e-06, 1.3047540563617633e-06, 1.2584599050733912e-06, 1.0044863475043152e-06, 1.0044888558008254e-06, 1.0044913640973358e-06, 1.0045062486228207e-06, 1.0045211585401347e-06, 1.0045236668616387e-06, 1.0045261751942757e-06, 1.0045286838384799e-06, 1.004531191133402e-06, 1.0045336999215094e-06, 1.0045362224355439e-06, 1.004538746759441e-06, 1.004541253944737e-06, 1.0045437622215247e-06, 1.0045462691234405e-06, 1.0045487673867214e-06, 1.0045512756837494e-06, 1.0045330661500387e-06, 1.0045314983896072e-06, 1.0045340066861176e-06, 1.0508595121822218e-06, 1.3048122384371079e-06, 1.3048147469973539e-06, 1.3048172706092426e-06, 1.3048251638664108e-06, 1.304932776445859e-06, 1.3050280023408756e-06, 1.30500941487857e-06]\n'`

If you look closely you'll see that the line from both files is extremely similar with some minor differences. For some reason difflib doesn't recognize the similar characters and just gives the whole line as a difference.

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Comment: Probably that would depend on the parser. What if you split the lines by space beforehand?

Comment: Is [something like this](https://www.online-python.com/3bnXuB9ac5) the desired output?

Comment: Yes but for some reason(I imagine it's to do with the length of the file since those files contain like 300 of the key-value pairs I have shown in the description), the '?' marker doesn't show up almost anywhere when I run this snippet on my code